# align, aligned and R Markdown

Tags: r, pandoc, markdown

I have been working in R Markdown, which supports LaTeX, including in display mode. I had the following snippet for displaying aligned equations

```
$$
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \beta_0 \\
b_1 &= \beta_1 \\
c_1 &= \beta_2 \\
d_1 &= \beta_3
\end{align}
$$
```

This worked great for me when I chose to output as HTML. I believe this uses MathJax.

However, when I changed the output format to PDF, I get the following error message:

> processing file: dummy.Rmd output file: dummy.knit.md
>
> ! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
>   (amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.
>
> See the amsmath package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.87 \end{align}
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source Error: pandoc document
>   conversion failed with error 43 Execution halted

When I change this to use `aligned` instead of `align`, it works with both.

This is an entire *.Rmd* file that shows the problem:

```
---
title: "dummy"
author: "Harold Ship"
date: "23 December 2015"
output: pdf_document
---


$$
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \beta_0 \\
b_1 &= \beta_1 \\
c_1 &= \beta_2 \\
d_1 &= \beta_3
\end{align}
$$
```

My question is, what is the difference between `align` and `aligned`, and why does `align` not work here with *pandoc*?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We have this question a lot of times. `align` is a full math environment, which must not be enclosed within (the deprecated!) `$$` form or `$`. `aligned` on the other hand requires to appear in a math-mode enabling environment. I don't know why `mathjax` does allow this syntax, but `pandoc` uses LaTeX externally (as far as  I know) and the error is reported.

Comment: What does the R Markdown code look like to achieve the LaTeX output you show?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, just to be clear (as it says this is unanswered), just write the align (without `$$`):

```
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \beta_0 \\
b_1 &= \beta_1 \\
c_1 &= \beta_2 \\
d_1 &= \beta_3
\end{align}
```

and **not**

```
$$
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \beta_0 \\
b_1 &= \beta_1 \\
c_1 &= \beta_2 \\
d_1 &= \beta_3
\end{align}
$$
```

Comment: ok, but why does this happen?

Comment: Because \begin{align} puts you in math mode already, you don't need the $$ to switch to math mode

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.
Yes, it should be

```
\begin{align}
\end{align}
```

from Latex point of view.
But "$$" is needed in Markdown files by tools like Obsidian.

So far I haven't got any solution but fix it by some scripts before exporting PDF.